# Django database modelform is_valid

Tags: django, validation

I just started some django some time ago, and i'm having a little of trouble to make this work.
I just want to make a group, who has members and those members make topics. Now, where i'm struggling is that i don't know how to add the topic to the group.

How can i make a topic thru showmessage ( if it is correct) and connecting the topic with the group.

Trying to make some conversation between people. Where later i can add people to the conversation.
It's been some days that i'm stuck help me!

my View

```
def showcreate(request):

p = Group.objects.all()


return render(request,'messages/showcreate/showcreate.html',{ 'p':p})    


def show(request, item):
items = item
p = Group.objects.all()

test='/show/'+item
print "showing item: 12, "+item
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = showmessage(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print "here too : "+request.POST['q']          ***** This is me trying to make it work***
        storyi = form.save(commit=False)
        storyi.Topics.user = request.user
        storyi.Topics.wichgroupe = request.POST['q']

        storyi.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(test)

else:
    form=StoryForm()





return render(request,'messages/show/show.html',{ 'p':p,'item':items,'form':form})
```

url

```
url(r'^show/(?P<item>\w+)', 'djangoproject.home.views.show', name='show' ),
url(r'^/showcreate', 'djangoproject.home.views.showcreate' ,name='showcreate' ),
```

Model

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    postit = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    createdat = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    wichgroupe = models.TextField(max_length=300, default="all")

def timer(self):
    return self.createdat




def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return self.postit


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    Topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

Forms:

```
class StoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic

        exclude =('user','createdat','comment','wichgroupe')



class Grouping(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group

        exclude =('Topics','members') 


class showmessage(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude=('user','createdat','comment','wichgroupe','Topics','members','name')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear, but I suspect that your problem is that you want to set the Group(s) at the time a Topic is created, but you've defined topics as an M2M in Group, not the other way around. So it's not happening automatically.

You can reference the set of Groups in a Topic thus:

```
mytopic.group_set
```

To render these on a form, you can add an inline formset for these related objects by following [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view).

Comment: Waw that's chinese to me man. haha :D
The problem i had is indeed that its not set in the group. I'll try to follow that doc. I already have read that one, but didn't understand it :/ I don't have an ID primary key on the topic, is that a problem? neither a foreign key? maybe those can help

Comment: The "id" primary key is set automatically on models for you, no need to add it. Since you have an M2M relationship, Django takes care of creating a "middle" table with foreign keys to both of the tables representing your models.

Comment: Sorry but i still don't know how they automatically connect :/ what is the group_set ? is that a function?  ( looked at inline factory thing but that didn't get far)

Comment: @nokker A relationship between two models runs two ways. In the model that defines the relationship, the property name is obvious enough, it's the name of the field you used. The name for the relationship from the other model is called the related_name (backref). By default, in Django, the related_name property is called OTHERCLASS_set. That works well enough unless you have more than one relationship to a model, in which case you need to set the related_name explicitly. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/relations/